# pushViewController don't work when my tableView is in an TabBar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a TableViewController in a TabBar.
When I select one cell of my tableView, I want start a new controller with pushViewController(MyNewController).

This is my code :

**In my TableView :**

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let myController = (storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController") as? MyViewController)!
            myController.parameter = self.tableau[indexPath.row]
            UINavigationController().pushViewController(myController, animated: true)
        }
```

**In my TabBar :**

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var controllerArray: [UIViewController] = []

    let controller: UIViewController = ClubPreviewListViewController()
    controller.title = "TEST"
    controllerArray.append(controller)

    self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)
  }
```

*(I use CAPSPageMenu for customize my TabBar, but it's not the problem, I have the same problem without)*

**In my controller :**

```
deinit {
    print ("TEST")
  }
```

When I select a cell, the log write "TEST" everytime I select but don't change the view.

I think it's my navigationController the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

Before I implement the TabBar, I use my TableView alone, and the push did works.

Sorry for my english ! Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**

I change my pushViewController :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let myController = (storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController") as? MyViewController)!
    myController.parameter = self.tableau[indexPath.row]
    //UINavigationController().pushViewController(myController, animated: true)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myController, animated: true)
  }
```

Same reaction.

My NavigationController isn't directly link with my TabBar. I need to create an other one ? I don't really understand how NavigationController works !

[This is my configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtUJL.jpg)

**EDIT2:**

**If I use the navigationController of my TabBar and not of my TableView, the view change !**

```
self.saveTabBarNavigationController.pushViewController(myController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an instance of a navigation controller on the line

```
UINavigationController().pushViewController(myController, animated: true)
```

Once this method finishes executing, the navigation controller and its view controllers will be deallocated because nothing retains your navigation controller. Causing 'TEST' to be printed in your `deinit()` function.

You should be obtaining the navigation controller that owns your current tab bar controller and pushing onto the stack using that. Without knowing the structure of your application it is difficult to know where your navigation controller is (if it exists).

Check your storyboard, but essentially try:

```
self.navigationController.pushViewController(myController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thank for your answer ! I edit my post, the result is same.

Comment: For be more precise, I use the navigationController of my TabBar and not of my TableView for execute the pushViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work only if you have a navigation embedded tabbar controller

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let myController = (storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController") as? MyViewController)!
            myController.parameter = self.tableau[indexPath.row]
            navigationController.pushViewController(myController, animated: true)
        }
```